# How to get the width in characters of a Kivy TextInput or Label

Tags: python, kivy

I have a `TextInput` in `Kivy` with long content. I want to know the width of the `TextInput` in characters. In other words, the length of the lines?

```
textinput = TextInput(text="Open source Python library for rapid development of applications that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps")
```

[image]

Comment: How about using `cursor_col` & `cursor_row`: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.cursor_col ?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور I think cursor_col gives you the position of cursor not the width of the line.

Comment: yes that's my point, do a combination check between `cursor_col` & `cursor_row` to store value of `cursor_col` and or next new line when `cursor_row` = +1 then that should be the length of the line, did you get my point here?

Comment: I got your point, this is  a hack. but not sure if it works well.

Comment: Well then, may be you can implement it as function and post it for kivy module... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check lines of `TextInput` using its `_lines` property. To get their lengths use `len()` builtin:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Print width"
        on_press: print([len(line) for line in ti._lines])
    TextInput
        text: "Open source Python library for rapid development of applications that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps"
        id: ti
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you . That gives the number of characters in that line not the total width.

Comment: You can't get total value since characters doesn't have fixed widths, for example . character has smaller width than X. Use that code to compare width of lines that consist only of . and X characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve this discussion:
In `TextInput._lines_labels` is field size (tuple) [0] with width of line. Each line. Just to iterate and look for the biggest and 'voilà'.
This works with any font (prop or not).

Radek